# AnimationRepetitions in Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, animation

Is there any way to stop an animation in Manipulate once it gets to the end? I assumed AnimationRepetitions would work like in ListAnimate, but it still loops for me. For Comparison:

```
ListAnimate[Table[i, {i, 0, 1, 0.1}], AnimationRepetitions -> 1](*Stops after one animation*)

Manipulate[i, {i, 0, 1, 0.1, Appearance -> "Open", AnimationRate -> 0.2, AnimationRunning -> True,   AnimationRepetitions -> 1}](*Loops Continuously*)
```

Comment: Ok, there's got to be a better way, but using `Manipulate[i, {i, 0, 1, 0.1, Appearance -> "Open", AnimationRate -> 0.2, AnimationRunning -> (i < 1)}]` works. Well, as long as you never touch the controls again... 

Comment: You received three answers and you’ve not upvoted, not accepted, not commented on whether any of them do what you want or don’t do what you want, or thanked them. These people are volunteering to help you. Pay them some respect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** Use `DefaultOptions -> {Animator -> AnimationRepetitions -> 1}` instead of `AnimationRepetitions -> 1`:

```
Manipulate[i, {i, 0, 1, 0.1, Appearance -> "Open", 
  AnimationRunning -> True, 
  DefaultOptions -> {Animator -> AnimationRepetitions -> 1}}]
```

[image]

Use  `AnimationRepetitions -> 2` to get

[image]

**Original answer:**

```
Manipulate[i, {i, 0, 1, 0.1, 
  Manipulator[##, 
    Appearance -> "Open", 
    AnimationRate -> 0.2, 
    AnimationRunning -> (i < 1)] &}]
```

[image]

Comment: This does exactly what I wanted, thanks! I'll have to look into these DefaultOptions/ControlType options.

Answer (score 2):

`ListAnimate` evidently constructs a `Manipulate`, and so we should be able to replicate its behavior. One way to figure out how `ListAnimate` works is to inspect its `InputForm` (click image to inspect output).

```
ListAnimate[Table[i, {i, 0, 1, 0.1}], 
  AnimationRepetitions -> 1] // InputForm
```

[image]

Unsurprisingly, `ListAnimate` uses a control of type `Animator`. The default `Manipulate` slider is a `Manipulator` (and `Slider` is distinct from both).
If we specify an `Animator` in `Manipulate`,
then we can use the `AnimationRepetitions` option.  Here's a slimmed down version:

```
Manipulate[i, {i, 0, 1, 0.1, 
  ControlType -> Animator, AnimationRepetitions -> 1}]
```

Add options to achieve the appearance desired.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured out a hack—hopefully someone comes along with something nicer. The trick is to put an invisible flip-flop variable into our `Manipulate`, and have it become `False` at the end of the range of the actual variable.

```
Manipulate[x = x && (i < 1); (*start body*) i,
    {i, 0, 1, 0.1, Appearance -> "Open", AnimationRate -> 0.2, AnimationRunning -> x},
    {x, {True, False}, ControlType -> None}]
```